# Failure to publish C# application using Produce a Single File option

Tags: c#, deployment

I have created a small application to deploy on a remote computer. The application compiles and runs locally in Visual Studio.
I publish locally without "Produce single file" ticked and the resulting .exe works fine when I test it on my computer, and when I copy the published folder to a remote computer, again it works fine.
If I then tick "produce single file" option, the .exe throws "Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at TestComputer.Program.Main(String[] args)". This happens both locally and when I copy it to a remote computer.

I wish to deploy the software without all the dlls exposed.

Details:
Developer environment:
Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.10.3
.Net Framework 4.8.04084
Language c#
Publish Profile:
Delete existing files: (false) - however I clear the publish folder each time I publish
Configuration: Active (Release)
Platform: Active (Any CPU)
Define Trace constant: Ticked
Nullable: Disabled
Treat warnings as errors: None
Target Framework: net5.0
Deployment mode: Self-contained
Target Runtime: win-x64
Produce single file: ticked
Enable ReadyToRun compilation: not ticked
Trim unused assemblies: Ticked

Not sure what other information I can provide.

Summary: I select "Produce single file" to reduce the number of deployable files, and it fails; I unselect "Produce single file" and it works

Question:
What settings must I change to enable me to use the "Produce Single File" option when publishing my software for remote deployment?

Comments:
Any help or suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Single file deployment essentially unpacks all the application files to a temporary folder. At least that was the behavior when I tested it.  There might be issues with the working directory if you are accessing any files. It would probably be helpful if you posted the source-code where the error occurs.

Comment: I hesitate to ask beginner programmers to delete the bin and obj folders in order to guarantee a clean build, because I frequently find that they have vital source files in those directories, and then they blame me for telling them to delete their only copy of the source they've been working on for the past three months.